# LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot( Panel ).Width may return 0 if I dont call UpdateLayout()

Tags: wpf

When opening a new panel, at some point its Loaded event is raised. In here, I try to call

```
LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot( Parent as Panel ).Width
```

According to [some guy](http://tinyurl.com/qhte9jx) the Loaded event is a prerequisite so that the layout is calculated etc., but I have met that condition. N.b. Loaded is called from root to children.

I tried invoking manually `UpdateLayout()` which does the job, but still I don't get why it doesn't work by itself.

Does anyone have any clue?

N.b. it seems to work when I call the method on my Parents' Parent!

Update
Im using a panel that has some width and height set. Then, I open and create a new canvas that has a panel. I want the most inner panel to stretch the available space - sometimes I get a proper value and sometimes not.
Im just trying to understand why it is not consistent, it seems to occur when a lot of processing is going on.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing some more code. I'm trying to recreate this but I haven't been able to get it to return 0.  Is there a Visual tree you can provide?  I'm trying with a Canvas inside of a Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [FrameworkElement.Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, I noticed this snippet:

> Be careful of reentrancy if your handler resets any properties that are interpreted by the layout system to mean that a new layout pass is required. (You might need to check the FrameworkPropertyMetadata values on the property if you are unsure of which properties can require a new layout pass if they are changed.)

My guess is that maybe you are, or a child control, or something of that nature is requiring a new layout pass once binding are hooking up and properties are getting changed.  With that being said, this sounds like usual behavior and your best bet is to call `UpdateLayout()` to ensure that the control is correctly sized.  I ran into the [Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which might be useful.

Also, notice this:

```
<Grid Width="0">
    <Canvas x:Name="Parent"
            Background="Red"
            Width="10"
            Loaded="Parent_Loaded">
        <Canvas x:Name="Child"
                Background="Yellow"
                Width="20"
                Height="20"
                Loaded="Child_Loaded" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Calling `LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot(Parent as Panel).Width;` will return 0, though all the objects will appear.  Though, if you make the Parent `Canvas` a `StackPanel` instead, you won't see anything appear.  This shows that `Canvas` has special layout logic (it doesn't inherit layout properties).  This is why showing more XAML might help us determine a more definitive solution.

Comment: Hey, I dont use canvases, but if it helps to repro, Im fine. Ill try the MetaData value. I read the Layout prior and about MeasureOverride etc. Thx so far! Ps updated my question.

Comment: Oh sorry the middle panel IS a canvas :/ Didnt realize this